# How to create a dataframe with a named-index and a unnamed-default-subindex

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe with index of dates. But in one date there would be one record or more.

so I wanna create a dataframe like :

```
                  A  B
2021-11-12   1    0  0
             2    1  1

2021-11-13   1    0  0
             2    1  0
             3    0  1
```

so could I append any row with the same date into this dataframe, and the subindex would be auto-increased?
Or is there any other way to save records with the same date index in one dataframe?

Comment: That's called MultiIndex. You can groupby dataset by two columns: df.groupby([col1, col2]).func()

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#remove counter level
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

#add  new row
#your code

#correct add new row after last datetime
df = df.sort_index()
#add subindex
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1), append=True)
```

Comment: Would `rank()` instead of `cumcount().add(1)` work too?

Comment: @Learningisamess - It depends, if sorted values same ouput, `cumcount` is more general